# How to send blog and page comment as email in Kaleo Workflow in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I'm able to send notification about new comments, but I'd like to send the comment as part of the email. Here's what I got so far:

```
<notification>
    <name>Notification</name>
    <description>Notifies about new blog or page comments</description>
    <template>

    <![CDATA[
    <p>
    There's a new comment at page ${page_url} by ${user_name} :
    <#if comment != "" >
    <br /><strong>${comment}</strong>
    </#if>
    </p>

    <p>With Love,<br /><strong>Liferay</strong></p>

    ]]>

    </template>
    <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
    <notification-type>email</notification-type>            
    <recipients>
        <role>
            <role-type>regular</role-type>
            <name>Portal Content Reviewer</name>
            <auto-create>false</auto-create>
        </role> 
    </recipients>
    <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
</notification>
```

How would I assign the ${page_url}, ${user_name} and ${comment}?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, $serviceContext has everything I needed. Note that I changed template language to velocity. For example:

```
<template>

<![CDATA[
## All attributes 
##set ( $debug = ${serviceContext.getAttributes()} )
## URL to page:
#set ( $url = ${serviceContext.getAttribute("contentURL")} )
##Latest comment
#set ( $body = ${serviceContext.getAttribute("body")} )
<p>
There's a new comment at page $url :
<br /><strong>$body</strong>
</p>
]]>

</template>
```